# How are the interfaces going to be replaced/augmented by the closures in Java?

Tags: java, closures, java-7

Java 7 will have closures ( finally ), and I wonder how the existing code using  single method classes/interfaces ( like Runnable, Comparator, etc )  will be used now.

Would that code be replaced? Will be a conversion of some sort? An extra method using the closure will be added?

Does anyone knows how is this going to work/what the plans are?

For instance, to use the FileFilter today we do:

```
....
File [] files = directory.listFiles( new FileFilter() 
                      public boolean accept( File file ) {
                          return file.getName().endsWith(".java");
                       }
                   });
```

Does anyone knows how is this going to work on Java7?

Maybe overloading the method File.listFiles to receive a closure?

```
File [] files = directory.listFiles(#(File file){
                    return file.getName().endsWith(".java");
                 });
```

Comment: http://stronglytypedblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/lambdas-in-java-preview-part-2.html see this article

Comment: @Bozho That's out of date since it doesn't reference the current version of the proposal, which doesn't have function types.

Comment: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-3.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These classes/interfaces are called SAM (Single Abstract Method) types, and conversion of lambdas to SAM types is a central part of the project lambda proposal for JDK7. In fact, the most recent iteration of the proposal removes function types and *only* allows lambdas as instances of SAM types. With the latest version of the syntax (which is **not** final), your example could be written like:

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles(#(file){file.getName().endsWith(".java")});
```

With `listFiles(FileFilter)` unchanged from what it is now.

You could also write

```
FileFilter javaFileFilter = {#(file){file.getName().endsWith(".java")};
```

You may also want to take a look at this [State of the Lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-2.html) document which is the latest update to the proposal and explains things in more detail. Note also that the specifics are all subject to change, though it's pretty certain that a lambda expression/block will be usable as a SAM type like I've described.

Comment: The `#x(y){ return z;}` is already pushed to JDK7, does this mean they're going to add these lambdas on top of what's in there currently or remove the `#` thing entirely? SAM conversion is nice though, it will allow huge parts of Java environment to be closure'd automatically.

Comment: I like `#int(int y){ return z;}` better than `{y->z}`

Comment: The syntax is not final, so it could change again, even back to the `#` thing. I got the feeling lots of people didn't like that though. One thing nice in the new version of the proposal is type inference for the arguments to the lambda, i.e. `{y -> z}` rather than `{int y -> z}`.

Comment: Also, lambdas can still be blocks rather than expressions so you can certainly write `{y -> return z;}`, it's just convenient to be able to exclude `return` and the `;` when you just need an expression (which is fairly common, I think).

Comment: Actually, the proposal would require you to write `{y -> yield z;}` rather than using `return`, in the hopes of saving `return` for a "long return" (return from the method the lambda is scoped in, essentially). Seems like most people aren't in favor of using `yield` for that though.

Comment: Isn't `yield` a whole different case than `return` in general? I can't imagine `collection.find({ -> yield it.value == x; });` feeling idiomatic at all.

Comment: Well, with a simple expression like that it would typically be idiomatic to just use the expression itself `collection.find({it -> it.value == x})`. I could be wrong, but I don't feel like `yield` is going to make the cut though.

Comment: Updated to the current syntax, which is more like `#(args){...}` with the types of the args optional if they can be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

Existing code isn't affected and won't need replacing.